# How to run numba.jit decorated function on GPU?

Tags: python, cuda, numba

I am trying to get into `numba gpu processing`. I have this `MWE`:

```
import numpy as np
import numba

@numba.njit
def function():
    ar = np.zeros((3, 3))
    for i in range(3):
        ar[i] = (1, 2, 3)
    return ar

ar = function()
print(ar)
```

Output:

```
[[1. 2. 3.]
 [1. 2. 3.]
 [1. 2. 3.]]
```

Now I want to run it on my `gpu`. I tried using following `decorators`:

```
@numba.njit(target='cuda')
@numba.njit(target='gpu')
@numba.cuda.jit
```

none of which work. Here are the error messages of above `decorators`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/amu/Desktop/RL_framework/help_functions/test.py", line 4, in <module>
    @numba.jit(target='cuda')
  File "/home/amu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/core/decorators.py", line 171, in jit
    targetoptions=options, **dispatcher_args)
  File "/home/amu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/core/decorators.py", line 179, in _jit
    dispatcher = registry.dispatcher_registry[target]
  File "/home/amu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/core/registry.py", line 96, in __getitem__
    return super(TargetRegistry, self).__getitem__(item)
KeyError: 'cuda'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/amu/Desktop/RL_framework/help_functions/test.py", line 4, in <module>
    @numba.njit(target='gpu')
  File "/home/amu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/core/decorators.py", line 236, in njit
    return jit(*args, **kws)
  File "/home/amu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/core/decorators.py", line 171, in jit
    targetoptions=options, **dispatcher_args)
  File "/home/amu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/core/decorators.py", line 179, in _jit
    dispatcher = registry.dispatcher_registry[target]
  File "/home/amu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/core/registry.py", line 96, in __getitem__
    return super(TargetRegistry, self).__getitem__(item)
KeyError: 'gpu'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/amu/Desktop/RL_framework/help_functions/test.py", line 4, in <module>
    @numba.cuda.jit()
  File "/home/amu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/__init__.py", line 140, in __getattr__
    ) from None
AttributeError: module 'numba' has no attribute 'cuda'
```

`numba.cuda` is not even recognized as `module function`. I have `numba 49.1` and `cudatoolkit 9.0` installed.

Do I have to change the `function` for this to work? I have a huge `numba.njit` function that I need to run on a `gpu`.

I was trying to learn more about `numba's cuda implementation` from:
http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.16.0/modules/numba.cuda.html

Thank you in advance.

**Edit:**

As @talonmies proposed I imported `cuda` explicitly from the `numba` module and outsourced the array creation:

```
import numpy as np
import numba
from numba import cuda

@numba.njit(target='cuda')
def function(ar=None):
    for i in range(3):
        ar[i] = (1, 2, 3)
    return ar

ar = np.zeros((3, 3))
ar_result = function(ar=ar)
print(ar_result)
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/amu/Desktop/RL_framework/help_functions/test.py", line 12, in <module>
    ar_result = function(ar=ar)
  File "/home/amu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/cuda/dispatcher.py", line 40, in __call__
    return self.compiled(*args, **kws)
TypeError: __call__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ar'
```

This `error` occurs with every of the aforementioned `decorators` except `@numba.njit`.

**Edit_2:**

When I try to run:

```
import numpy as np
import numba
from numba import cuda

@numba.jit(target='cuda')
def function(ar):
    for i in range(3):
        ar[i] = (1,2,3)

ar = np.zeros((3, 3))
function(ar)
print(ar)
```

the output is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/amu/Desktop/RL_framework/help_functions/test.py", line 11, in <module>
    function(ar)
  File "/home/amu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/cuda/dispatcher.py", line 40, in __call__
    return self.compiled(*args, **kws)
  File "/home/amu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/cuda/compiler.py", line 758, in __call__
    kernel = self.specialize(*args)
  File "/home/amu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/cuda/compiler.py", line 769, in specialize
    kernel = self.compile(argtypes)
  File "/home/amu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/cuda/compiler.py", line 785, in compile
    **self.targetoptions)
  File "/home/amu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/core/compiler_lock.py", line 32, in _acquire_compile_lock
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: compile_kernel() got an unexpected keyword argument 'boundscheck'
```

Comment: Array creation isn't supported on the GPU so your code won't work, but you need to explicitly import the cuda module from numba to get the cuda decorator or target

Comment: would it work if you create the arrays outside the numba decorated function and then pass them to the numba decorated function?

Comment: That is the only way Numba works with the GPU. You have to pass arrays as arguments

Comment: Would you like to answer your own question for future visitors with the same problem? I will happily upvote it

Comment: I will try to solve and answer it

Comment: @talonmies I expanded my post. Please take a look

Comment: For your latest edit 2, this seems to be a [known issue](https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/5868) with recent versions of `numba`.  You may be able to work around it by changing the kernel launch from: `function(ar)` to `function[1,1](ar)` which is equivalent.

Comment: @talonmies With this workaround `@cuda.jit` seems to work while the others still don't. I'll continue my work with it. Thanks alot for your time

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Three points:

1. You have to explicitly import the cuda module from numba to use it (this isn't specific to numba, all python libraries work like this)
2. The nopython mode (`njit`) doesn't support the CUDA target
3. Array creation, return values, keyword arguments are not supported in Numba for CUDA code

I can fix all that like this:

```
...: import numpy as np 
...: import numba 
...: from numba import cuda 
...:  
...: @numba.jit(target='cuda') 
...: def function(ar): 
...:     for i in range(3): 
...:         ar[i] = (1,2,3)   
...:  
...: ar = np.zeros((3, 3)) 
...: function(ar) 
...: print(ar) 

[[1. 2. 3.]
 [1. 2. 3.]
 [1. 2. 3.]]
```

Comment: I tried running your code, please take a look at the **Edit_2** section

Comment: Doing the `from numba import cuda` did the job, thank you.

Comment: Doesn’t work anymore: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72341089/1267833 also says so in the dox: https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/parallel.html (first paragraph)