# Unrecognized options: {'target'} when using @jit(target="cuda")

Tags: python, cuda, numba

I have optimized some python code using the decorator @jit from numba library. However, I want to indicate to @jit to use my GPU device explicitly. From: [Difference between @cuda.jit and @jit(target='gpu')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35890045/difference-between-cuda-jit-and-jittarget-gpu), I understand that I need to use @jit(target="cuda") to do it.

I tried to do it by doing something like this:

```
from numba import jit, cuda

@jit(target='cuda')  # The code runs normally without (target='cuda')
def function(args):
    # some code
```

And I got the following error:

```
KeyError: "Unrecognized options: {'target'}. Known options are dict_keys(['_nrt', 'boundscheck', 'debug', 'error_model', 'fastmath', 'forceinline', 'forceobj', 'inline', 'looplift', 'no_cfunc_wrapper', 'no_cpython_wrapper', 'no_rewrites', 'nogil', 'nopython', 'parallel', 'target_backend'])"
```

I have read this: [How to run numba.jit decorated function on GPU?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62794341/how-to-run-numba-jit-decorated-function-on-gpu) but the solution did not work.

I would appreciate some help to make @jit(target='cuda') work without rewriting the code using @cuda.jit as this last one is for writing CUDA kernel in Python and compile and run it.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, **CUDA targets are not supported anymore for `jit` and`njit`** ([it was supported few years ago](https://github.com/numba/numba/blob/fcd5c74814a8605c45ef0da3ae6d05286779856d/numba/core/decorators.py#L45) as a wrapper to `cuda.jit`). It is [**not documented**](https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/jit-compilation.html). There is however such parameter for `numba.vectorize` and `numba.guvectorize`. [In the Numba code](https://github.com/numba/numba/blob/468647dddde27ee8af124c97dfcd20c35c4a2bc6/numba/core/decorators.py#L26), one can see that there is a parameter called `target_backend` which is obviously not used (anymore?). There is a parameter call `_target` which is read but not meant to be used directly by end-users. Additionally, it [calls `cuda.jit`](https://github.com/numba/numba/blob/468647dddde27ee8af124c97dfcd20c35c4a2bc6/numba/core/decorators.py#L203) in the end anyway. Such part of the code seems to be dead.

If you want to write a GPU-based code, then **please use `numba.vectorize` and `numba.guvectorize` or `cuda.jit`** (the last is quite low-level compared to the two first).

Comment: Thanks for replying! If it were possible, how can I know which GPU is jit using? In my case I have a Intel(R) UHD Graphics 620 and a Nvidia GPU but I do not know which is jit using. There is a way to "force" Python to use the Nvidia GPU?

Comment: You can try to use CUDA tools & profilers to check that (possibly nvidia-smi and nvvp). Numba only support CUDA which is AFAIK only supported on Nvidia GPUs, not Intel iGPUs (at least not without experimental tweaks). Thus, the Numba code can only run on the Nvidia GPUs.

Answer (score 6):

I faced a similar issue and got through by changing `target` to `target_backend`

So, my decorator goes like `@jit(target_backend="cuda")`

*It's just a quick-fix that worked for me, I didn't dig further*

Comment: "*that worked for me*" It should not. It will simply ignored by (recent version of) Numba. See my answer. Did you *check* your code actually used your GPU?